# Remove index.php from website home url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I Have index.php in my website home page and tried to remove it for some SEO purposes as follows but i am unable to do this by using the scripts in my htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

how i can do this to remove the index.php

Comment: Try robots.txt file, as an alternate of .htaccess for SEO, you can use **no index, no follow**.

Comment: any way doing this through HTACCESS?

Comment: The htaccess will make your website work without having to put the index.php but will not prevent robots of going to it. Try adding a redirect if you'd like, maybe a sitemap or robot.txt? But your htaccess seems fine...

Comment: In the same time, you can remove index.php from all your URI, because `/?var=value` is the same as `/index.php/?var=value` ! it's enough to use `<a href="/">...</a>` !

Comment: there are hundreds of questions at SO that already answered this

Comment: "I Have index.php in my website home page" - are you even using a _front controller_ (as everyone is assuming)? Or do you simply have an `index.php` in the URL of your "home page" that you want to remove (as your question states)?

Answer (score 0):

> This is the basic rule to hide index.php from the URL. Put this in
>   your root .htaccess file. mod_rewrite must be enabled with PHP and
>   this will work for the PHP version higher than 5.2.6.

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Wordpress uses this. And it works since a long time.

Comment: I am working with custom php website it will still work?

Comment: I don't see why not - this looks fine to me